# add-apt-repository not working

Tags: 12.04, repository

I can't add a simple PHP repository on 12.04, it just hangs for infinite time until you cancel it with CTRL+Z

[image]

I need this to update PHP from 5.3 to 5.6, already ran update and upgrade.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 is EOL as of last year.  Please upgrade to a supported version of Ubuntu.  See https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life as well as https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release

Comment: Does that mean it will solve the issue?

Comment: Installing a supported version should.  Also, we support them here when they are still supported by canonical themselves.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I noted in your gif is that your account is root. Its a doubt.why you need "sudo" . [image]

Second thing there is no ppa:ondrej/php repository for Ubuntu 12.04. Hence, you are unable to add the ppa:ondrej/php. Please consider to update your ubuntu. [image]

[image]